# Variable display in a specific order

Tags: javascript, alert

I have this variable:

```
var hours = "lu9,lu10,lu11,ma9,ma10,ma11,mi9,mi10,mi11";
```

Then I need to display an alert those same values​​, but ordered as follows:

> lu9,ma9,mi9,lu10,ma10,mi10,lu11,ma11,mi11

I'm using this code but can not get it to work:

```
var hours = "lu9,lu10,lu11,ma9,ma10,ma11,mi9,mi10,mi11";

myExit = hours.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
    var reg = /\d+/;
    var num = 2 * (+(0 + a.match(reg)) - +(0 + b.match(reg)));
    var str = a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    return num + str;
});

alert (myExit);
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you!

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close. You just needed to change `.slice()` to `.split(',')`.

```
var hours = "lu9,lu10,lu11,ma9,ma10,ma11,mi9,mi10,mi11";

myExit = hours.split(',').sort(function (a, b) {
    var reg = /\d+/;
    var num = 2 * (+(0 + a.match(reg)) - +(0 + b.match(reg)));
    var str = a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    return num + str;
});

alert(myExit);
```

Complementary [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/absynce/K3nvQ/)